# Hide soft keyboard not working when EditText in bottom sheet

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard

I have EditText in BottomSheet. When BottomSheet show and I tap the EditText then the soft keyboard is showing. But how I can hide the soft keyboard when the length of value Edittext is 6 in BottomSheet?

[image]

I have some logic like this:

```
private fun showBottomSheet() {
        val binding: BottomSheetSetupEasyPinBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(activity), R.layout.bottom_sheet_setup_easy_pin, null, false)
        binding.fragment = this
        binding.vm = vm
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        //For hide softKeyboard
        binding.etEasyPinConfirmation.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                           count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                       before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (s.length == 6) {
                    hideSoftKeyboard()
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Length is 6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        })

        bottomSheet.setContentView(binding.root)
        bottomSheet.setCancelable(false)
        bottomSheet.show()
    }
```

And this is the function for hiding soft keyboard:

```
fun hideSoftKeyboard() {
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view!!.windowToken, 0)
    }
```

And this is the global variable and declaration that variable in `onViewCreated`:

```
// global variable
private lateinit var inputMethodManager : InputMethodManager
..
// in onViewCreated
inputMethodManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
```

But when the length of value EditText is 6, the Toast is showing, and I already debugging it the function is executed, but the keyboard not hide. Does anyone know why my code is not working for hiding a soft keyboard in BottomSheet? Because if EditText is not in BottomSheet, this function is a success for hiding the soft keyboard

Comment: Pass the view from bottomsheet to `hideSoftKeyboard`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used the next code:

```
fun hideSoftKeyboardBottomSheet(view: View) {
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

and insert the view form Bottom Sheet into this function

Comment: add in the fun ->

val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
    InputMethodManager

Comment: Final something works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this updated method kotlin version

```
    fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
    }

    fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
    InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Before proceeding further check that are you getting events of editext or button while clicking on it try to print log in addTextChangedListener().

I think you are not getting the event I had this issue before.